# gender specific treatment arms in clinical trial

Tags: interaction, clinical-trials

if we were designing a clinical trial to compare an old and new treatment and there was strong a priori evidence of a treatment gender interaction (ie new treatment does better than old in men, worse in women) would one possible way to investigate this be to have 1 (control) arm for the old treatment and 2 new (active) treatment arms for the new treatment, 1 for just men and 1 for just women ie 3 arms in total and compare both new treatment arms to the control arm ? Would we need to control the gender proportions in the control arm in some way or is it just a suboptimal idea ? what other approaches could there be ?

Answer (score 0):

I think that the only correct way to address this would be stratified randomization (ie creating two separate randomization lists, one for men, and one for women).

A good article on this is [Kernan et al, J Clin Epidemiol 1999](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0895435698001383).

If you wish to have an even number of men and women enrolled, you might with to include only a fraction of men (which are often over-represented in some fields, eg cardiology), but this could create some issues with external validity.

Comment: many thanks, Joe for the helpful answer and journal article, it seems to confirm that gender specific arms are a very non standard idea for dealing with the issue. I'll suggest stratified randomization.